# Message pump and D3D11 DXGI in separate threads

Tags: architecture, directx, directx11, windows, multithreading

I have read:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/dxgi-best-practices#multithreading-and-dxgi

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-dxgi#multithread-considerations

### Threading setup

**Main thread (Main loop)**: Create window and run the message pump (PeekMessage()).
Add messages (keyboard, mouse, ...) to a thread safe double buffered queue.

**Render thread (Render loop)**: Create DirectX 11 stuff (Device, ...).
Read game state N from game thread. Update GPU buffers, draw calls, swapchain present.

**Game Thread (Game loop)**: Create game world. Game logic, physics, update game state N + 1.

**Thread pool**: spawn additional worker threads.

According to the posted links, DXGI may call SendMessage (synchronous call), which can lead to deadlock
when the message pump and DXGI are on separate threads. But as far as I understand it,
there shouldn't be any problems in this case with the main thread, because the only thing it does is to
pump messages and add them to a thread safe queue. or am I missing something?
Can a deadlock still occur when switching to an exclusive fullscreen mode?
Calling the swapchain present? or other DXGI calls?
I won't add any other code in the main thread that could make the message pump thread wait on the render thread.

If this is ok, how do I reduce the CPU usage in the main thread? Running this loop will consume 100% of the CPU core.
But at the same time, we want the input to feel responsive.

Comment: You may be interested in [Is Dedicating A Thread To Inputs A Good Idea In Game Design?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/187185/39518) I know intuitively it might seem like gathering inputs in the smallest hot loop possible, with no game sim work in between, would be a good way to reduce latency, but it does not actually shorten the time gap between an input event and the perceptible feedback. It *does* however create room for new bugs and inconsistencies.

Comment: @DMGregory Sorry for the late reply. I need to timestamp each message in order to implement these techniques:

https://us.forums.blizzard.com/en/overwatch/t/new-feature-%E2%80%93-high-precision-mouse-input-gameplay-option/422094


https://www.gamedev.net/tutorials/programming/general-and-gameplay-programming/asynchronous-keyboard-input-for-fixed-time-step-games-r3959/